# Unable to import GAE api in python shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have downloaded the GAE SDK and would like to use its api from the python shell.

I have placed the following in my .bashrc where google_appengine is the folder where I have unzipped the SDK -

```
#GAE
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/google_appengine/
```

Now I have created a new project using virtualenv. When I fire up a python shell and try to use its api, I get the following error -

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

Can someone please help me debug this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppEngine can't be run from the Python shell, there too much wireup that needs to be done (and done by dev_server) in order for the platform to work.
What you can do is have a [AppEngine application that is an interactive Python console](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/shell) ([Live](http://con.appspot.com/console/)) that can run the AppEngine platform and all supported python libraries.

Comment: Guys thanks for the anwser. Muhammed the project page for the link posted by you seems down. So though I can see the documentation, I am however unable to download the code, will appreciate if you can provide link.

Comment: Shay, the project contains this in yaml - "url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py" - However I neither have a variable defined $PYTHON_LIB, nor does my GAE SDK have the handler.py. What do I do ?

Comment: use [bultins to work with remote api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Builtin_Handlers)

Comment: Said the xoogler that was working on app eninge for the pass five years.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of setup you are missing just by doing this.  You will find 
it much easier to use the remote api shell.  Just run `python $PATH_TO_APPENGINE/remote_api_shell.py appid`  and this will give you a shell with all of the paths correctly defined.  You don't actually have to connect to a remote instance, though that will be useful.  You can't really use any of the models through a shell with out some datastore backend.  You can also use the remote api shell to connect to a local dev server instance.

See a good article on using it here https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api